# How to disappear some cell in ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewTag viewTag;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        viewTag = new ViewTag((LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row), (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv));
        convertView.setTag(viewTag);
    }
    else {
        viewTag = (ViewTag) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewTag.tv.setText(lvt.getTextAt(position));
    viewTag.tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    boolean show = lvt.getShowAt(position);
    if(show) {
        viewTag.tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewTag.ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        viewTag.ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

I use above code in BaseAdapter to show list view.
lvt is an application global data.
If show is true, I want to disappear the cell.
But not delete the data.
But my method will not show data, but show the divider line.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify getCount as below:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lvt.sizeTestArray(); i++) {
        if(!lvt.getfiv1At(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And change position in getView as below:

```
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < lvt.sizeTestArray(); i++) {
        if(!lvt.getfiv1At(i)) {
            if(count == position) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

It seems do well now.
But I am not sure any bug exist now.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do what you are asking for.
if BaseAdater.count() return the count of all the itmes(even the ones you don't want to show), than you can't tell the getView() method to "ignore" some of the logic items.

what I suggest you to do is to filter your data list (create a new lvt) to be only with the items you want the listView to show, and only then - the adapter should work with this new logic data.

in your case, as you suspect - the "lvt.getShowAt(position) = false" should be your filter indicator

Comment: But this method may cause 'Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' no use.

Comment: @brian: you don't need to call the listView.setAdapter() twice.   call it only after you created the new filterd list

Comment: I means if original data changed, the new one will not auto update

Comment: @brian: but on the relevant activity - you don't want to show the original data, but only the filterd data.  your adaper need to work with this new filterd data.  I don't understand exactly what's the problem with that?

Comment: @brian: I think I've got you now.      if from some reason the original data changed - then you must update also the filterd list afterwards..   no escape from that...   if it's too complicated to make it work this way - then maybe you should consider refactoring your data stracture (lvt) to be more adaptable to this states..

Comment: If item click, I will make change in original data according to the position in original. It will not know position of item in original.

Comment: @brian: item click don't suppose to cause directly to change in data. if it suppose to do so in you app - then you'll have to deal it somehow with your own desired implementation. still I believe my previous comment about do some changes in you data structures should solve all of this problems. dealing with adapter which some of his data is not needed to be showed - indicates usually about wrong design

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *hide* items from the ListView I would prefer you to take seperate `lvt`(show true only) rather than trying to manipulate the views.